# How to apply changes stored on a dataframe to another dataframe?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My base dataframe looks like this:
**HeroNamesDF**

```
id gen name  surname supername
1  1   Clarc Kent    BATMAN
2  1   Bruce Smith   BATMAN
3  2   Clark Kent    SUPERMAN
```

And then I have another one with the corrections: **CorrectionsDF**

```
id gen attribute value
1  1   supername SUPERMAN
1  1   name      Clark
2  1   surname   Wayne
```

My aproach to the problem was to do this

```
CorrectionsDF.select(id, gen).distinct().collect().map(r => {
  val id = r(0)
  val gen = r(1)

  val corrections = CorrectionsDF.filter(col("id") === lit(id) and col("gen") === lit(gen))
  val candidates  = HeroNamesDF.filter(col("id") === lit(id) and col("gen") === lit(gen))

  candidates.columns.map(column => {
    val change = corrections.where(col("attribute") === lit(column)).select("id", "gen", "value")

    candidates.select("id", "gen", column)
     .join(change, Seq("id", "gen"), "full")
     .withColumn(column, when(col("value").isNotNull, col("value")).otherwise(col(column)))
     .drop("value")
 }).reduce((df1, df2) => df1.join(df2, Seq("id", "gen")) )

}
```

Expected output:

```
id gen name  surname supername
1  1   Clark     Kent         SUPERMAN
2  1   Bruce    Wayne     BATMAN
3  2   Clark     Kent         SUPERMAN
```

And I would like to get rid of the **.collect()** but I can't make it work.

Comment: Can you please add expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly the example, one inner join combined with a group by should be sufficient in your case. With the group by we will generate a map, using 
[collect_list](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#collect_list) and [map_from_arrays](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#map_from_arrays), which will contain the aggregated data for every id/gen pair i.e `{"name" : "Clarc", "surname" : "Kent", "superaname" : "BATMAN"}`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{collect_list, map_from_arrays, coalesce}

val hdf = (load hero df)
val cdf = (load corrections df)

hdf.join(cdf, Seq("id", "gen"), "left")
   .groupBy(hdf("id"), hdf("gen"))
   .agg(
      map_from_arrays(
         collect_list("attribute"), // the keys
         collect_list("value") // the values
      ).as("m"),
      first("firstname").as("firstname"),
      first("lastname").as("surname"),
      first("supername").as("supername")
    )
   .select(
     $"id", 
     $"gen", 
     coalesce($"m".getItem("name"), $"firstname").as("firstname"),
     coalesce($"m".getItem("surname"), $"surname").as("surname"),
     coalesce($"m".getItem("supername"), $"supername").as("supername")
   )
```